# bower in VS2017 is not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bower, visual-studio-2017, bower-install, asp.net-core-1.1

When I using bower manager to install 'animate' package, There is an exception:

`EMALFORMED Failed to read C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\FRANK-PC-Frank\bower\a2a424217f809672e8fe80ddeab36781-21084-Ho4ioc\bower.json
Additional error details:
Unexpected token }`

I don't know why bower.cmd not modified bower.json in project. It seems to want to modify the temp bower.json(Which I can't find it,using the path provided by bower logger).

How to solve it? and Why the bower package manager is not easy to use?

full log(vs2017 v15.2) as follow:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External;%PATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
bower animate#*             not-cached https://github.com/joshuapekera/animate.git#*
bower animate#*                resolve https://github.com/joshuapekera/animate.git#*
bower animate#*               checkout 1.0.1

bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:   8% (51/635)
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  10% (68/635), 220.01 KiB | 164.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  12% (77/635), 332.01 KiB | 158.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  12% (80/635), 620.01 KiB | 228.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  13% (85/635), 1020.01 KiB | 236.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  13% (86/635), 1.12 MiB | 237.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  13% (87/635), 1.39 MiB | 256.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  14% (89/635), 1.63 MiB | 273.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  14% (94/635), 1.96 MiB | 259.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  15% (96/635), 2.34 MiB | 282.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  41% (261/635), 2.86 MiB | 339.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  59% (375/635), 3.24 MiB | 386.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  96% (610/635), 4.14 MiB | 517.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1         EMALFORMED Failed to read C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\FRANK-PC-Frank\bower\a2a424217f809672e8fe80ddeab36781-21084-Ho4ioc\bower.json
Additional error details:
Unexpected token }
```

[image]

update log in VS2017 Preview:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install animate#1.0.1 --force-latest --save
bower bootstrap#3.3.7       not-cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.7
bower bootstrap#3.3.7          resolve https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.7
bower animate#1.0.1         not-cached https://github.com/joshuapekera/animate.git#1.0.1
bower animate#1.0.1            resolve https://github.com/joshuapekera/animate.git#1.0.1
bower animate#1.0.1           checkout 1.0.1
bower bootstrap#3.3.7         checkout v3.3.7
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  72% (127/176), 900.00 KiB | 164.00 KiB/s
bower animate#1.0.1           progress Receiving objects:  80% (141/176), 1.14 MiB | 183.00 KiB/s
bower bootstrap#3.3.7         resolved https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.7
bower animate#1.0.1         EMALFORMED Failed to read C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\DESKTOP-CBTHUS9-Frank\bower\a2a424217f809672e8fe80ddeab36781-12852-ixWkIa\bower.json
Additional error details:
Unexpected token }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by manually removing all of the entries in the 'dependencies' property of the bower.json, all trailing carriage returns and whitespaces.  Afterwards, I right-clicked the bower.json and used 'Manage Bower Packages...' and re-installed those packages via the tool.  After that, right-click 'Restore Packages' was successfully retrieving them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. In my case it was a bug within Visual Studio 2017. I updated to the latest version of visual studio 2017 (15.3) and it worked fine after that.

You may have to remove the dependencies in the bower.json file and then re add them via Manage Bower Packages after the update.